# Get slope of linear fit

Tags: fitting

This may seem silly, but I've been crazy for the last hour trying to find a way to automate the linear fit of my data. All I need is the slope.

Say I have some data `list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};` and want to find the slope that fits it best, something like `m = Slope[list]`, so that I can use `m` wherever I want.

`Fit[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, x}, x]` returns me `4.0284*10^-15 + 1. x`, in wich case the value I want is `1.`. How can I get that value programmaticly? The function `Fit` returns the results in a not very useful form... Why?

Notice that I have 2337 curves to fit. I can't do them all by eye or copy and paste. Surely I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: `D[Fit[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, x}, x], x]`?

Comment: `Coefficient[Fit[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, x}, x], x]` works too.

Comment: Or if you want a sophisticated way, `lm = LinearModelFit[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, x}, x]; First@Pick[lm["BestFitParameters"], lm["BasisFunctions"], x]`.  There are lots of fitting functions. Try `?*Fit`.

Comment: @J.M. Better than `D`, esp. when the model has other functions.

Comment: if you've given your LinearModelFit a variable name like lm then Coefficient[ lm[x], x ] will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting my comment into a function:

```
bestFitSlope[data_] := Module[{lm, x},
   lm = LinearModelFit[data, {1, x}, x]; 
   First@Pick[lm["BestFitParameters"], lm["BasisFunctions"], x]
   ];
```

Example. Suppose you have a list of datasets, then you can [`Map` (`/@`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the function `bestFitSlope` over the list.

```
SeedRandom[0, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
n = 6;                        (* number of datasets to make uo *)
slopes = RandomReal[5, n];    (* slopes of the lines *)
datasets = Table[
   20 i + slopes[[i]] x + RandomReal[{-2, 2}], (* line + noise *)
   {i, n}, {x, 15}];

ListPlot@datasets
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The we can get the slopes of the fitted lines and compare them with the "theoretical" slopes:

```
bestFitSlope /@ datasets
slopes
(*
{2.12046, 2.90695, 0.189475, 3.72127, 0.314697, 4.21059}
{2.1471, 2.90036, 0.151295, 3.81398, 0.253895, 4.23242}
*)
```

Note: The function `bestFitSlope` throws away the linear model it constructs. You might want to keep it for the other information it contains (see [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html)).

Comment: Yes. The solution does seem to be to define the `Slope[list_]:=...` function. I just wasn't used to manipulating data if not in lists or value output.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way.

```
lineData = Fit[list, {1, x}, x];
val  = Last[lineData];
val /. x -> 1
```

This will give you the value of the slope of the linear fit.

Comment: Note, that this only works, if the result is always returned exactly in the form `a + b x`, and never as `b x + a` (or only `b x`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Plot your `list`:

```
ListPlot[list, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}, 
Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

And since you asking: *something like `m = Slope[list]`, so that I can use `m` wherever I want*. You certainly remember the [concept of slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)

[image]

And you should read [Defining Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html), [How to | Create Definitions for Variables and Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateDefinitionsForVariablesAndFunctions.html), [Setting Up Functions with Optional Arguments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html), [Functions as Procedures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAsProcedures.html) and [Defining Variables and Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html)

So can do:

```
m[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)

m[2, 4, 2, 4]
```

> 1